# C# Asp.Net attributes model validation using .netstandard nuget package system.componentmodel.dataannotations does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, .net-standard, model-validation

I am in the middle of upgrading from netframework to netcore. I now have an asp.net mvc 5 web app that references a project with my models in it. Model Validation was used and some of those models have **[ValidationAttribute]** attributes from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations **assembly**. However, the validation stopped working right after upgrading the Models project to netstandard and adding the System.ComponentModel.Annotations **nuget package**. I think that the Model Validation doesn't work with the nuget package, only with the assembly, they also have a bit different assembly name, but the same namespace.

So here are my questions:

1. Can you confirm that it doesn't work like this or am I missing
   something?
2. Is there a good approach to get around this or do I have to use some custom validation until I fully upgrade to netcore?

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments i've decided to add a little sample of what used to work but now it doesn't

The first class is a model with a validation attribute

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyWebApp.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The second class is an ApiController

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAppSandBox
{
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Student model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("The model is not valid");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This is a very simple example and it validates the model correctly using .NetFramework. However, if you put the student class in a .netstandard project, the ModelState.IsValid property will always be true.

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and include a complete sample of code that used to work, but now does not. If you made any changes during the conversion, then please include the before + after version of the same code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue the other day, then noticed a warning from Visual Studio:

> "Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly."

[image: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.]

Clicking on this added the following entry to the `runtime/assemblyBinding` section of web.config:

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
```

That sorted out the issue for me, hopefully it'll help someone else out too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this might've been the issue. However, I moved away from this a long time ago, already, so if this will get more upvotes, I will mark this as the accepted answer